# Jenkins with a Cocos2d-X project

Tags: c++, jenkins, cocos2d-x

I have just recently moved into developing Cocos2d-X application for Android devices, from native Android application development. I am looking to configure my Cocos2d-X C++/JAVA project in a JENKINS environment.

Has anyone any experience of using JENKINS with cocos2d-X projects ? Any tips on where i can get started ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cutom scrip option, for example if you use the cocos2d-x model for build you can build your project with the custom command "make", in adition you can use statically code check, bla, bla, ...
I use too my machine as slave for no put the build environment in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It depends upon the build tool you are using. I am using Ant with Eclipse. Try to read about building an Android Project from Command Line Using ant or gradle. and there you go,Include "Build Step"->  "Execute shell" in jenkins. 
You have to manually check for all dependencies.